# Edit Elment into Edit Item

Tags: java, spring, customization, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I changed the value of a field present in the table list view in the editor area of ​​an entity (making a custom renderer that hides the first 5 digits), as OOTB behaves, by double clicking on the table list view, a window opens called "Edit element", in this window there is also the field that I had modified in the table list view with the difference that in this window all the figures are visible, how can I hide the figures of a field also in this window? On the backoffice-config I don't find anything that could refer to this window.
Thanks a lot.

table list view:
[image]

window edit element:
[image]

Comment: List view and edit view having pointed different attribute?

Comment: @RaushanKumar I not think, but probably the edit item is an OOTB functionality.

Comment: @RaushanKumar not easy to customize this.. tightly coupled OOTB function I think.

Comment: Hi @mike
I think you do it via Decorated Editor. please have a look at the concept.
https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/8ba9714d866910149452fd7cd395e186.html